# php Class not found even in require_once file

Tags: php, class

I have a weird problem. There's some Plans class in its Plans.php file that is included in a main php, but seems to not be loaded by the system.

Look, here you are the action.php file

```
<?php

// action.php gets 3 parameters:
//  - CONTROLLER: one on AUTH, SYSTEM, USER, ADS 
//  - ACTIVITY: one on LOGIN, PLANS, CONTACTS, GUESTS, CONFIG, MESSAGES
//  - ACTION: LIST, VIEW, EDIT, INSERT, UPDATE

include './config/config.php';
include './utils/Connect_db.php';
require_once './model/Plans.php';
require_once './controllers/MainController.php';
require_once './controllers/AuthController.php';
require_once './controllers/UserController.php';
require_once './classes/ValidateUser.php';

if (class_exists('Plans')) {
    error_log('action: Plans exists');
} else {
    error_log('action: Plans NOT exists');
}

if (class_exists('AuthController')) {
    error_log('action: AuthController exists');
} else {
    error_log('action: AuthController NOT exists');
}

$main = new MainController();

?>
```

I've put some *class_exists* function to check if **Plans** class is loaded or not.

Here is the error_log file output:

```
[13-Feb-2015 01:04:39 Europe/Brussels] action: Plans NOT exists
[13-Feb-2015 01:04:39 Europe/Brussels] action: AuthController exists
```

Obviously later use of Plans class results in **Plans class Not Found**

Here you are my Plans.php file:

```
<?php

class Plans {

    private $_con;
    private $_sql;

    function __construct($users_id, $plans_id) {

        $this->_con = Connect_db();

        switch(func_num_args()) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1: // One argument to be users_id
                $this->_sql = "(SELECT u.users_nic, g.status, p.*"
                ." FROM users u, plans p LEFT JOIN guests g"
                ." ON g.plans_id=p.plans_id AND g.users_id=p.users_id"
                ." WHERE u.users_id=p.users_id AND p.users_id=".$users_id.")"
                    . " UNION"
                    . " (SELECT u.users_nic, g.status, p.*"
                ." FROM plans p, users u, guests g"
                ." WHERE u.users_id=p.users_id AND g.plans_id=p.plans_id"
                ." AND g.users_id=".$_users_id." AND p.users_id!=".$users_id." )"
                    ." ORDER BY día DESC";
                break;
            case 2: // Two arguments to be users_id y plans_id
                $this->_sql = "SELECT u.users_nic, g.status, p.*"
                ." FROM users u, plans p"
                ." LEFT JOIN guests g"
                ." ON g.plans_id=p.plans_id AND g.users_id=".$users_id
                ." WHERE u.users_id=p.users_id AND p.plans_id=".$plans_id;
                break;
        }

    } 

    function __destruct(){
        // TO DO
        mysqli_close($this->_con);
    }

    public function dir() {

        $res = mysqli_query($this->_con, $this->_sql)
            or die("Fallo de Consulta");

        $arrSalida = array();

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            $arrSalida[] = $fila;
        }

        return $arrSalida;

    }
}
?>
```

What's wrong with this class? The switch is done to implement __construct with one or two arguments. And **model** and **classes** folders exists and files are there with the right names.

Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: What does your file directory structure look like?

Comment: One php folder with model, config, utils, controllers and classes folders. action.php hangs directly from php folder while Plans.php is inside model folder and ValidateUser.php is inside classes

Comment: Try this: `require_once getcwd() . '/models/Plans.php';`.

Comment: Hi Darren, same error: [13-Feb-2015 11:35:34 Europe/Brussels] plans_list: Plans NOT exists  ... I think it should be something related with the class definition itself. Php don't likes something and class is not loaded. Unfortunatelly there's no traces at log file. Don't know if log level could be increased in php.

Comment: Hi guys... incredible it sounds the problem was some hidden character in the class definition. I made a new file, typing everything without copy/paste and it worked... maybe some twisted 1 or broken 0 :-) ... thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incredible it sounds the problem was in a **hidden character** in my php code. I deleted the file and created a new one typing the code again without copy/paste and the problem was gone. Sadly I didn't keep the file to analyze it with another text editor were I could see the bad character.